# Function is undefined using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

In my ASP.NET page using the following code:

```
<asp:ScriptManager  ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        function ValMail() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("<%= Email.ClientID%>");
        var Resp = <%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>;
        if (Resp != false)
            txt.nodeValue = "";
            txt.focus();
            };
    </script>
    <asp:Label ID="EmailLabel" runat="server" AssociatedControlID="Email">E-mail:</asp:Label>
    <asp:TextBox ID="Email" runat="server" TabIndex="4" CssClass="textEntry" CausesValidation="True" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" OnClientClick="ValMail()" />
```

My problem is that when I click on the button comes to executes the command `OnClientClick="ValMail()"`
Holds the execution of the program and throw me an error `javascript runtime error: ValMail() is undefined`
But even sow I'm clicking `Ignore` and the code goes into the script executes only the line `var Resp = <%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>;` and nothing from the rest of the code in javascript
I’m completely unfamiliar with javascript coding and most with the thrown errors. Is someone to assist me with that?

Comment: You should debug by looking a the source rather than the generating code. What's the output of this code?

Comment: The output is True or False and then I'm trying to handle it inside the script. I set a hold in the code behind and then trying to go step by step and that's why I see that nothing is executed from the other lines of the java code

Comment: if `IsValidEmail(Email.Text)` returns a string, that string needs quoting for javascript variable. As @plalx mentioned...need code browser sees to debug. How it gets generated is irrelevant

Comment: Where is the function `IsValidEmail`? Is it on the code behind?

Comment: also...javascript `true` and `false` are case sensitive and are lowercase

Comment: @Mt.Schneiders Yes is in the codebehind

Comment: @nnnnnn The right way is ` if (Resp != false) {txt.Value = "";     txt.focus();};` or `{if (Resp != false) txt.Value = ""; txt.focus(); };`

Comment: @LefterisGkinis - No, that second option isn't right, it still leaves the `txt.focus()` as not belonging to the `if`. The first is right, and is what I already put in my answer. (I deleted my comment when I posted an answer.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't explain the "ValMail() is undefined" error. However, if you use your browser's "View Page Source" option I think you'll find that this line:

```
var Resp = <%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>;
```

...is sent to the browser as this:

```
var Resp = True;
```

or:

```
var Resp = False;
```

Either of which is a syntax error in JavaScript because JS is case sensitive and you need a lowercase t or f in the boolean `true` and `false`. So either modify that ASP code to put out `true` or `false` in all lowercase or add quotes so that JS treats it as a string and then tests as a string with the matching uppercase F:

```
var Resp = "<%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>";
if (Resp != "False")
```

Which, given that `Resp` is only used in one place after its declaration, you could shrink down to:

```
if ("<%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>" != "False") {
```

Also I think you want `txt.value`, not `txt.nodeValue`.

Finally, judging by the indenting, I suspect you want both lines under the `if` to belong to the `if`, in which case they need to be contained in a block designated by `{` and `}` - you currently have no opening `{` which means only the line immediately after the `if` belongs to it.

Putting that all together:

```
function ValMail() {
    var txt = document.getElementById("<%= Email.ClientID%>");
    if ("<%IsValidEmail(Email.Text)%>" != "False") {
        txt.value = "";
        txt.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: YES YES YES YES the code now is going perfect and the lines are executed just fine. BUT if I don't want to use the button how can I call the function?

Comment: If you mean that you want the function to be executed automatically when the page loads just call it indirectly with `window.onload = ValMail;` - or move the `<script>` element to the end of the page (just before the closing `</body>` tag) and add `ValMail();` immediately after the function to call it - if you call it with `ValMail()` with the script above the elements it wants to manipulate then it won't work, because if you do it will execute before the browser has parsed those elements.

Comment: NO no I don't want to executed automatically but I want to executed when I leave the TextBox (with mouse or with TAB). I presume that it must be a way to do that. Because I see now that the Variable `Email.Text` is not passed to the code behind!!!

Comment: While I'm debugging it I see that `function ValMail() {
        var txt = document.getElementById("LeftNavigationHolder_Email");
        if ("" != "False") {
            txt.value = "";
            txt.focus();
        }
    }`

Comment: Adding _onblur="ValMail();"_ to the text input should run the function when the user tabs or clicks out of the field. Or it might be _OnClientBlur=..._ - it's been years since I did ASP. The code behind only runs when the page is first requested or after a submit.